# How to add image byte array in parameter for showing in rdlc/crystal report in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports, rdlc

I created data set and added column there and passing information from my controller but all information are showing accept the byte array. I want to show image from database byte array in my crystal report. Given below the controller's action  code:

```
var finalResult = healthCardViewMod.ToList().Select(listPrint => new
           {
            ImageByte = listPrint.ImageByte,
            ImagePath = listPrint.ImagePath,
            MemberName = listPrint.MemberName == null ? "" : 
            listPrint.MemberName,
            MemberId = listPrint.MemberId == null ? "" : listPrint.MemberId,
            MemberDob = listPrint.MemberDob == null ? 
            DateTime.Now.ToString() : listPrint.MemberDob.ToString(),
            CommDate = listPrint.CommDate == null ? DateTime.Now.ToString() 
            : listPrint.CommDate.ToString(),
            OrganizationName = listPrint.OrganizationName
            }).ToList();

     ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

     rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/CrystalReport1.rpt")));
     rd.SetDataSource(finalResult);

     Response.ClearHeaders();
     Stream stream = 
     rd.ExportToStream(
     CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; 
        filename='EmployeeList_" + DateTime.Now + ".pdf'");
        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: Have you added the ImageByte field in crystal report ? Because whenever data fields are passed to crystal report it creates columns for everything except for byte array. Just drag and drop the field from field explorer and add it to the report.